# Identify soundtrack from "Tales from the Consoles Episode 01 | Sonic.exe"

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

What is the name of the music played in [this Youtube video from minute 11:35 to 12:25](https://youtu.be/NZIFewmNYaw?t=694)?

Can anyone tell me, what is this ambient song?

Answer (score 1):

[Peter Gundry - A Journey's End](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRqHFWtqG8w)

It is from the game Journey.